# IIS8 ASP.NET : What effect does private memory limit have on GC and Cache

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I'm having a real tough time of the documentation.  I can verify with my eyes a worker process will attempt to stay bellow the private memory limit set on the application pool however I can not turn up the documentation around this.  I've seen it mentioned in a blog post as well that the cache will trim once it reaches a certain threshold of the memory limit, however I am also unable to locate this in the documentation.  What I can find is that there is a process model "memoryLimit" documented but the 4.0-4.5 documents don't go into detail about it.  Prior documentation indicates it's related to the physical memory in the machine but I'm not so sure that's the case anymore.. So my questions are three:

1. What effect does private memory limit have on GC(is it the same as
   general memory pressure?) ?
2. What effect does private memroy limit have on the cache?
3. Where is this documented?!